# 403 Forbidden when GET parameter name and value are integers

Tags: apache, url, get

does anyone know what is causing server to issue 403 when GET parameter name and value are integers, for example:

http://example.com?1=1 bad
http://example.com?a=b&1=2&c=d bad
http://example.com?a=b&c=d good

> Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4
>   FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 Server at www.example.com Port 80

Thanks.

Comment: you have a custom httpd.conf or .htaccess that can overwrite this?

Comment: @BookOfZeus I dunno about httpd.conf, seen same behavior o some pages, I figure it has something to do with SQLi, `x' OR 1=1`...

Comment: what's the content of your .htaccess?